# Zookeeper on EC2 when login hostname changes automatically

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, server, apache-zookeeper, putty

When I login my ec2 instances with Putty hostname for that node changes to hostname of another node. I dont know why it happens. Because of that i cannot install zookeeper

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu/Debian:

`echo "myhostname" > /etc/hostname`

For Ubuntu/Debian/RedHat/CentOS/AMI:

put `myhostname` to file `/etc/hosts` after each `localhost`

Use a commnad `hostnamectl set-hostname myhostname`